# Detect iOS Autocomplete Suggestion Key Press?

Tags: javascript, ios, frontend, keyboard-events, web-frontend

On `iOS` keyboard the top row sometimes has autocomplete suggestions.

The `keydown` event is not fired when the user clicks on one of these autocomplete suggestions.

Is it possible to listen for an event when a user clicks on one of the autocomplete suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `input` event described here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_inputevent.asp

For example, say you have a contenteditable `<div>` element:

```
<div contenteditable id="content"></div>
```

Then typing into said `<div>` can listen for the `input` event and get all this helpful info. You can look at the `event.data` property to see a full word that was selected via iOS's suggestions.

```
document.querySelector('#content').addEventListener('input', event => {
  console.log('event.data ==', event.data);
  console.log('Other stuff:', {
    dataTransfer: event.dataTransfer,
    targetRanges: event.getTargetRanges(),
    inputType: event.inputType,
    isComposing: event.isComposing,
  });
});
```